# How do I set number of objects failed threshold trigger to stop S3 Batch Operations job to custom value other than 1000?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-batch

I read from this doc
"After the first 1000 objects have been processed, S3 Batch Operations examines and monitors the overall failure rate, and will stop the job if the rate exceeds 50%."
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/

How to I control this value, to say, 100? 50? Or any custom value for that nature that suits my business case?

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a supported option with S3 Batch Operations